# jquery ui: Nested accordion is all screwed up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some code that is generated using php. It outputs a nested accordion. For some reason the accordion looks very screwed up. So much so that I can't even explain. Here is the code that is generated:

```
<div class='accordion'>
    <h3>2012</h3>
    <div class='accordion'>
        <h3>October 2012</h3>
        <div>October 5, 2012</div>
        <div>October 5, 2012</div>
        <div>October 4, 2012</div>
        <div>October 4, 2012</div>
        <div>October 4, 2012</div>
        <div>October 3, 2012</div>
        <div>October 3, 2012</div>
        <div>October 3, 2012</div>
        <div>October 1, 2012</div>
        <div>October 1, 2012</div>
        <div>October 1, 2012</div>
        <div>October 1, 2012</div>
    </div>
    <div class='accordion'>
        <h3>September 2012</h3>
        <div>September 30, 2012</div>
        <div>September 29, 2012</div>
        <div>September 29, 2012</div>
        <div>September 26, 2012</div>
        <div>September 26, 2012</div>
        <div>September 25, 2012</div>
        <div>September 24, 2012</div>
        <div>September 19, 2012</div>
        <div>September 19, 2012</div>
        <div>September 19, 2012</div>
        <div>September 19, 2012</div>
        <div>September 19, 2012</div>
        <div>September 11, 2012</div>
        <div>September 5, 2012</div>
    </div>
    <div class='accordion'>
        <h3>August 2012</h3>
        <div>August 19, 2012</div>
        <div>August 17, 2012</div>
        <div>August 9, 2012</div>
        <div>August 4, 2012</div>
        <div>August 4, 2012</div>
        <div>August 4, 2012</div>
        <div>August 4, 2012</div>
        <div>August 4, 2012</div>
        <div>August 4, 2012</div>
        <div>August 2, 2012</div>
    </div>
    <div class='accordion'>
        <h3>July 2012</h3>
        <div>July 1, 2012</div>
        <div>July 1, 2012</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call it using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.accordion').accordion({
            autoHeight:false,
            collapsible:true,
            active:false});
});
```

This looks like it should work. To see what it's doing go to:
http://lonewolfdigital.com/misc/test/

Comment: There should be a single accordion titled '2012'. Inside it should be 4 nested accordions, each containing the individual divs.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xh2eK/

Comment: yes. looks like you put the contents in a list instead of using divs like I did. Does it not like divs for some reason?

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the html structure that the accordion takes.. it has a heading.. then the contents.. it doesn't have multiple div contents inside one heading.. what you can do is inside the "div" content have multiple divs

Comment: works fine here with divs also  I'll write up an answer explaining the changes

Comment: I got it working on the test. Thank. When you get the answer I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An accordion has a heading.. then it's contents.. so what you want is this structure

```
<div class='accordion'> <!-- tells its an accordion -->
     <h3>2012</h3> <!-- this is the first heading  -->

    <div class='accordion'> <!-- tells its another accordion  -->
         <h3>October 2012</h3> <!-- first heading  -->

        <div> <!-- the headings content - only one content per heading and so on  -->
            <div>October 5, 2012</div>
            <div>October 5, 2012</div>
            <div>October 4, 2012</div>
            <div>October 4, 2012</div>
            <div>October 4, 2012</div>
            <div>October 3, 2012</div>
            <div>October 3, 2012</div>
            <div>October 3, 2012</div>
            <div>October 1, 2012</div>
            <div>October 1, 2012</div>
            <div>October 1, 2012</div>
            <div>October 1, 2012</div>
        </div>
         <h3>September 2012</h3>

        <div>
            <div>September 30, 2012</div>
            <div>September 29, 2012</div>
            <div>September 29, 2012</div>
            <div>September 26, 2012</div>
            <div>September 26, 2012</div>
            <div>September 25, 2012</div>
            <div>September 24, 2012</div>
            <div>September 19, 2012</div>
            <div>September 19, 2012</div>
            <div>September 19, 2012</div>
            <div>September 19, 2012</div>
            <div>September 19, 2012</div>
            <div>September 11, 2012</div>
            <div>September 5, 2012</div>
        </div>
         <h3>August 2012</h3>

        <div>
            <div>August 19, 2012</div>
            <div>August 17, 2012</div>
            <div>August 9, 2012</div>
            <div>August 4, 2012</div>
            <div>August 4, 2012</div>
            <div>August 4, 2012</div>
            <div>August 4, 2012</div>
            <div>August 4, 2012</div>
            <div>August 4, 2012</div>
            <div>August 2, 2012</div>
        </div>
         <h3>July 2012</h3>

        <div>
            <div>July 1, 2012</div>
            <div>July 1, 2012</div>
        </div>
    </div>​
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8qW3/

Answer (score 0):

See the following fiddle for your code wrapped in the proper divs:
http://jsfiddle.net/ufEyn/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.subaccordion,.accordion1').accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Comment: @LoneWolfPR You still have two accordions named `accordion` nested one under the other.

Comment: yeah, i switched it back when the last suggestion didn't work.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR I see what you did now--you need to enclose everything inside the accordion in a singular <div>--JQuery UI doesn't combine them all into one.